# How Do I create DataFrame by using Pyspark DataFrame as I do by pandas？

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two lists like below:

[image]

I want to merge these lists to such a DataFrame as below:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call this "merging"

Comment: Why can't you do it in Pandas, then use Pyspark to load the pandas dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The reason why I wouldn't like to use pandas is that pandas is too heavy to apply it to big data.
Anyway, I'd like to create(not merging, sorry) DataFrame like what I posted before.

Comment: It's not clear how large your data is... Pandas can handle GB of data on a single machine just fine. If you really wanted to have a distributed Pandas, I would suggest Dask rather than Spark. In any case, it's not clear what you've tried in order to get the result you're looking for

Comment: Well, I've tried to create DataFrame by 
"""
pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.concat([od_all,df_female_od]),index=range(len(df_female_st))).set_index(df_female_st).replace(np.nan,1)
"""

,and I could not do that by spark.

How can I do that by Dask? I suppose Dask creates aggregation of arrays, which I cannot create DataFrame like above.